# Getting error in naming series collection in a chart in VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I am having some problem in Excel VBA. When I try to run the below code; it says:

```
Error 1004:Unable to get the name property of the series class!
```

This error happens at this line of code : (product is defined earlier as string Zyvox and others)

```
If namec.Name = product Then
```

What should I do? I have tried other things too like

```
   ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(p).name = product
```

But to no avail! Please help!

```
Public Sub chartBlue()

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, p As Integer, namec As Series


For i = 4 To Sheets.Count
    Sheets(i).Activate
    For j = 1 To Sheets(i).ChartObjects.Count
        Sheets(i).ChartObjects(j).Activate
        ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select


        For p = 1 To ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Count
        Set namec = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(p)


            If namec.Name = product Then
               namec.Border.ColorIndex = 5

            End If

        Next p
    Next j
  '  Windows(Reportname).Activate
    Sheets(i).Range("A1").Activate
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: does the issue still persist? Could you please comment. In the mean time try this as well:e.g. `ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=""someseries1""" ` try to set the `Name` of the Series to the value (e.g. `someseries1`) that you have assigned to `Product` `String` variable. Or simply try to do a msgbox on `Namec.Name()`. Could that be you have an empty Chart.. So it fails at this point: `For p = 1 To ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Count
        Set namec = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(p)` since you are starting your `Loop with pre-defined lower bound 1`...?

Comment: Agree with @bonCodigo, 1st step, like that series's name **REALLY** exist. If issue persist, you may want to post more detail here. E.g. how you create the chart---VBA Code. Or a snapshot of the chart itself will be useful.

Comment: It works now. I don't know how but it worked in 2007 but not in 2003. Thanks for all your support!! Yeah it is working on empty charts also.

Answer (score 2):

Amit, I ran your code on a sample worksheet and it works fine! The only thing that was missing is the declaration and setting of the variable `product`, but you mentioned that you did that. So, first make sure that `product` is declared as string and has the content. Then, set a breakpoint in the line

```
If namec.Name = product Then
```

and run the code. Inspect the content of both, `namec.Name` as well as `product` and see where it differs

Comment: It gives an error at the point namec.name : Run time error 1004 Unable to get the name property of the series class!; Please help. Also this code colors the series line for the product.

Comment: Have you checked if all the references are available? In VBE, go to Tools->References and see if anything is labelled as 'MISSING:'. If a reference is not correct, the compilation sometimes stalls at very odd places...

Comment: Yeah indeed. I checked , nothing was Missing.. I am quite perplexed.

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment. So the problem still persists?!? Save your code to another, blank workbook (with a chart) and see if it compiles there...

Comment: +1 for the steps you have given (I forgot to vote up yesterday ;)